# Point domain to sub-directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to point https://stateofmotion.sg/ to https://stateofmotion.sg/2021. I've tried to do this in my .htaccess file but it doesn't seem to work. In other words, I would like to see the 2021 page immediately when I enter https://stateofmotion.sg/.

Here is the code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?stateofmotion.sg/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2021/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /2021/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?stateofmotion.sg/$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ 2021/index.html [L]
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help. Thank you!

Best
Matt

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, could you please try following rules. This should rewrite your base url eg--> `https://stateofmotion.sg/` to `https://stateofmotion.sg/2021`, please make sure your clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)stateofmotion\.sg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule ^ 2021 [L]
```

OR without RewriteCond: make sure you place either above OR following code only once at a time.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)stateofmotion\.sg
RewriteRule ^/?$ 2021 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

make a try with the below code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)? stateofmotion.sg$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ 2021[L]
```